# Retrieve IP address data from mongodb in pymongo using regular expression or pattern matching

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, ip, database

I'm using mongodb to store my data and i used to following python script to execute a query to find count of a collection,

```
collection_name = "prodresultlistCollection_%s_%s" %(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
my_collection = mydb[collection_name]

parameter = "IP addr"
ip = "10.20.30.40"
count1 = my_collection.count({ '$and': [{parameter:'%s' %(ip)}]})
```

Here the `count1` shows the number of rows that have the given `ip` value. This `count1` query only counts the number of rows where `ip == IP addr`. But in the database the `IP addr` attribute can have one or more IP in the format below,

```
10.20.30.40
10.20.30.40,20.35.45.55
10.20.30.40,20.35.45.55,10.10.10.10
etc...
```

Consider the `IP addr` value in database is `10.20.30.40,20.35.45.55`, then whatever pattern of `ip` is given the query should retrieve this row.

```
ip = 10
ip = 10.20
ip = 10.20.30
ip = 10.20.30.40
ip = 20
ip = 20.35
ip = 20.35.45
ip = 20.35.45.55
```

In all the above cases of `ip` given to the `count1` query, that specific row in database with the `IP addr` value of `10.20.30.40,20.35.45.55` should be retrieved. I tried to solve the problem using regular expressions as given below but it shows Syntax Error in pymongo and in some cases no rows are retrieved.

```
count1 = my_collection.count({ '$and': [{parameter:/'%s'/ %(ip)}]})
count1 = my_collection.count({ '$and': [{parameter:'/%s/' %(ip)}]})
count1 = my_collection.count({ '$and': [{parameter:/%s/ %(ip)}]})
```

Then i tried to match the IP pattern using regular expression using the code below:

```
import re

IP = raw_input("Enter the IP: ")
S = IP.split(".")
IP_DB = "10.20.30.40,20.35.45.55"

if len(S)==4:
    obj = re.search(r"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$",IP_DB)
elif len(S)==3:
    obj = re.search(r"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}",IP_DB)
elif len(S)==2:
    obj = re.search(r"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}",IP_DB)
elif len(S)==1:
    obj = re.search(r"^\d{1,3}",IP_DB)
else:
    print "Invalid IP!!!"

if obj:
    print obj.group()
else:
    print "Nothing found!!!"
```

But the problem here is, it only compares the pattern of the IP and not the values. For any value of IP given in the pattern `xx.xx.xx.xx`, this code returns `true` for matching/searching result. Also the 2nd part of the IP is not considered here. Is there a better way to solve this problem? I need to retrieve rows from the mongodb database using `ip` in such a way that any pattern of `ip` given matches the `IP addr` in the database. What kind of syntax or regular expression should be given in the `count1` query to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a `regex` pattern, pymongo accepts a regular `Python regex object`. So you can do the following:

```
import re

regex = re.compile('{}'.format(YOUR_IP_ADDR))

count = my_collection.find({'ip_addr_field': regex}).count()
```